# Identifying geometry format?

Tags: geometry, standards

I have a database with geometries encoded in a field in the following format:

'1  L 410012.85,416177.69; +30.16,4; 12.46,0; 13.35,-0.67'

Where L specifies that it is a Polyline, then 410012.85,416177.69 is the starting point. The rest of vertices are calculated by adding or subtracting X and Y. So for example:

- Vertex 1 is starting point (X=410012.85 Y=416177.69)
- Vertex number 2 is X=410012.85+30.16 Y=416177.69+4
- Vertex 3 is Vertex2(X)+12.46 Vertex2(Y)+0
- Vertex 4 is Vertex3(X)+13.35 Vertex3(Y)-0.67

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Generating a standard format by splitting the text in multiple parts is something that probably can be done. However, I'd be more interested in knowing if it is actually a known format in GIS (does it have a name?) and if already exists a way of translating it into a standard format.

Comment: A differential storage algorithm like this is quite efficient, and is in fact used by Esri in their ST_GEOMETRY implementation (albeit in binary form). Given how simple it is to parse, I wonder at your goals in this question: Isn't it more important to make effective use of it than to get a name and have an existing translator?

Comment: Thanks Vince. I'd like to make effective use of this format, but in the end I'll need it translated so it can be put in our current database system. To begin my research and having something to start looking at, it would be really useful to know if this format has a name, is it actually a GIS standard, or if already exists a translator. My thought was that it is an old format, not used in the current standards, but according to your answer, seems that Esri is currently using a similar or identical approach? Could it be the literal translation of the binary form used by Esri? Kind regards.

Comment: There's a difference between comments and answers. These are just comments. It's not a literal translation because ST_GEOMETRY uses integer encoding as well. But given an inefficient representation like ASCII, it's not a bad idea. Standardhood is too easy to achieve; if you want a name you should talk to the provider.